# SQL getting cumulative sum of a table in group by where the column itself is cumulative sum

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have a table that contains column cumulative_sum which is a cumulative sum of it previous values.

So, for account A cumulative_sum for 2022-01 is 12, and for 2022-02 it's 24 meaning there has been increment of 12.

| month | cumulative_sum | account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 12 | A |
| 2022-02 | 24 | A |
| 2022-03 | 36 | A |
| 2022-01 | 12 | B |
| 2022-03 | 24 | B |

Now, what I want is something like:

| month | cumulative_sum | account |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 24 | A, B |
| 2022-02* | 36 | A, B |
| 2022-03 | 60 | A,B |

Is this possible to do or even doable?

As you can see even though for 2nd row we don't have any month value, I would still like to get sum from it's earlier value.

Comment: Better show the original sample data instead of a result of a query we don't know fetching data we don't know.

Comment: Sorry, but this is just a simplified version of the problem I have ran into.

If you just run group by on the source table you will get following output for row two: 2022-02  > 24  > A

However what I am asking for is if it's possible to produce what is in the output.

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify your question, but you are using words as "cumulative" and "simplified", so this makes the impression you don't show us the original input data? That's confusing and I guess, therefore no one answered yet. Please make sure the first table shows the real sample data as it is in your table and the second table shows the exepected result. Also note clarifications should rather be added editing your question than using comments.